# widget jquery see all elements using progress bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

using this tutorial http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_create

Hi, I add my progress bar  to my element "myID" and I can see it on the page so it works

```
$("#myID").progressbar({
        value: 99
      });
```

Why wont this return true. the documentaion says it should as the progress bar is added to it

```
var s = $('#myID').is( ":data( 'ui-progressbar' )" );
console.log(s); // returns false  but should return true  why
```

Comment: jquery ui version used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the spaces are causing the problem

```
var s = $('#myID').is(":data(ui-progressbar)");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TFm2b/)